# Named placeholders should not be numeric values in Serilog and advantages of using structured logging VS string interpolation in Serilog?

Tags: c#, .net-core, serilog, structured-logging, serilog-aspnetcore

Why in Serilog, named placeholders should not be numeric values, but numeric placeholders do not generate a warning with `Console.WriteLine`.

e.g:

```
_log.LogInformation("some data - {0} and data2: {1} ", data1, data2);
```

causes a warning

> named placeholders should not be numeric values

and following is working fine without any warnings

```
_log.LogInformation("some data - {data1} and data2: {data2} ", data1, data2);
```

But why does this code here not generate any warning?

```
Console.WriteLine("some data - {0} and data2: {1} ", data1, data2);
```

And what is the advantages of using structured logging over string interpolation in Serilog?

Comment: structured logging gives you key-value pairs of the values. logging services can make this searchable and filterable. also WriteLine != LogInformation. there's a different format string that each expect

Comment: This question is rooted in a fundamental misunderstanding of string formatting and logging. Also, please avoid adding "and why X?" in your questions. Each SO question should be self-contained. If you have multiple questions, raise multiple posts in SO one for each question.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1053/ (everyone has TILs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Background info on structured logging in Serilog and in general (covers what message templates are intended to achieve, which will answer your question far more completely than attempting to replicate that here):

- https://serilog.net
- https://messagetemplates.org/

**TL;DR: Message Templates are an (technically upward compatible) extension of message template semantics as used in `String.Format`, with specific conventions. As the message says: for log messages, you should not use numbered placeholders, use string identifiers for field names instead.**

The `LogInformation` call in your example is defined by `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`, which shares rules and conventions about how you add fields to structured log messages. If you've wired that to Serilog, then it will need to meet its rules too (which are pretty much identical). Serilog itself will actually permit you to use the numbers as field ids, but you're missing the point (easy to read/query semantically meaningful log messages) if you do that. For this reason the [`Serilog Analyzer`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Suchiman.SerilogAnalyzer) rules (and probably some MEL based ones too) will encourage you to use names rather than values.